# Understanding visuals in VEINS and Omnet++

Tags: simulation, omnet++, veins, sumo

I was able to create routing config files for sumo, link them with Omnet++ and VEINS. When I ran the VEINS simulation, I see the movement of the vehicles and exchange of information between them as seen here :

[image]

Questions:

1. Where can I find more exact information about the color of nodes : when the node circle is green, red, etc.?
2. What do these blue connecting lines in the debug mode mean? Where can I find more information?

Comment: You are most likely running the TraCIDemo11p demo application layer from the Veins tutorial. Everything you are asking is in its source code. It's only a few dozen lines.

Comment: Thank you! I also see the scheduled accident and accident resolved events. How can I find the configs or source of those? Sorry if the questions are basic...

Comment: They are also in this file. Look for par() calls, as discussed in the OMNeT++ TicToc tutorial. If you are unsure about their use, just do the tutorial again.

Answer (score 0):

When the node receives a message named `"data"` it calls `onData()` which, among others, does the animations you are asking for

```
else if (std::string(wsm->getName()) == "data") {
    onData(wsm);
```

---

> 1. Where can I find more exact information about the color of nodes :
>      when the node circle is green, red, etc.?

```
void TraCIDemo11p::onData(WaveShortMessage* wsm) {
    // Here is the green color for the nodes
    findHost()->getDisplayString().updateWith("r=16,green");
    // Here the blue lines are drawn
    annotations->scheduleErase(1, annotations->drawLine(wsm->getSenderPos(), mobility->getPositionAt(simTime()), "blue"));

    if (mobility->getRoadId()[0] != ':') traciVehicle->changeRoute(wsm->getWsmData(), 9999);
    if (!sentMessage) sendMessage(wsm->getWsmData());
}
```

> 2. What do these blue connecting lines in the debug mode mean? Where can
>      I find more information?

When a node receives a data message, a blue line is drawn by the receiving node, from itself to the node that sent the message.